# Swift converting signed array of Int [int8] to unsigned array of Int [UInt8]

Tags: ios, swift, arrays, unsigned, signed

How to convert signed array of [Int8] to unsigned array of [UInt8].

```
 let arryData: [Int8] =  [-108, 11, -107, -14, 35, -57, -116, 118, 54, 91, 12, 67, 21, 29, -44, 111]
```

I just want to convert this above into array of Unsigned [UInt8]. How to achieve this in swift.? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your intention is to convert signed 8-bit integers to
unsigned ones *with the same bit representation* (e.g. `-1 -> 255`):

```
let intArray: [Int8] =  [0, 1, 2, 127, -1, -2, -128]
let uintArray = intArray.map { UInt8(bitPattern: $0) }

print(uintArray)
// [0, 1, 2, 127, 255, 254, 128]
```

Comment: This is crazy. I like the static behavior of swift. But the difference between uint and int in C api is supper fungible. It should be fixable without CPU cycles and map complexity.

Comment: how can i cast Int to UInt8

Comment: @TroyHarvey the map is just a way to iterate over the array

Comment: @HRaval you would do UInt8(bitPattern: Int8(intVal))

Answer (score 4):

**[Int8] -> [UInt8]**

You haven't specified how you want to treat negative values; by flipping them to their positive counterpart or by removing them. Below follows both cases.

---

Transforming negative values to positive ones by flipping sign:

```
let arrayData: [Int8] =  [-108, 11, -107, -14, 35, -57, -116, 118, 54, 91, 12, 67, 21, 29, -44, 111]
let arrayDataUnsigned = arrayData.map { UInt8(abs($0)) }
    /* [108, 11, 107, 14, 35, 57, 116, 118, 54, 91, 
        12, 67, 21, 29, 44, 111] */
```

Or, by removing the negative values:

```
let arrayDataUnsigned = arrayData.flatMap { $0 < 0 ? nil : UInt8($0) }
    /* [11, 35, 118, 54, 91, 12, 67, 21, 29, 111] */
```

Comment: No actually this is not the way to convert Int8 to UInt8. ex. UInt8(bitPattern: -108) return 148 i.e Unsigned value. I am expecting something like this.

Comment: this UInt8(bitPattern: -108) will only work for single value not for an array. So looking for something which will convert entire singed to Unsigned values

Comment: Since you didn't specify what you ment by _converting_ in your question, the two  alternatives above do indeed cover two ways to convert an `Int8` array to a `UInt8` array. However, since `Int8` is a byte, perhaps I should've inferred that you referred to bitpattern conversion. For this method: see MartinR:s answer; making use of `.map` as above but with the `UInt8(bitPattern:)` initializer, allowing you convert each element of your array by each elements' bit pattern.