# how to store negative number in UInt8 Array

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

i'm new to iOS development, when I store an unsigned number in `byte/UInt8` array it shows an error.

```
var iv: [UInt8] = [69, 56, 30, -78, -8, 9, 81, 37, -116, 56, -4, 95, -106]
```

> negative integer **78** overflows when stored in unsigned type **UInt8**

***edited***

i'm using it for encryption purpose, if i change it to signed the cipher output will be changed any other solution? or how to convert it to signed in swift

Comment: why don't you just use signed int8 ?

Comment: `UInt` generally stands for "**un**signed integer".  i.e. no negatives.

Comment: You can't, unsigned integers are always, well, unsigned. They can't be negative. Change the type to `Int8`.

Comment: "UInt generally stands for "unsigned integer"  Which means a non negative normal numbers

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867528/swift-converting-signed-array-of-int-int8-to-unsigned-array-of-int-uint8.

Comment: actually I'm using AES encryption and it has constructor parameter as Uint Array so i can't be able to use Int8?

Comment: Thanks @MartinR this works by converting unsigned int to signed

Answer (score 4):

You can't, UInt is unsigned integer number means non negative, change the type of your array to Int

Comment: Thank @Marat but how can i convert it to unsigned array?

Answer (score 1):

`UInt8` is `Unsigned Integer` and it has range of `0...255` so you cannot store value beyond this range means non negative and with in `255`, if you want to store negative value then use `Int8` and its range is `-128...127`.

Answer (score 0):

uint8 is an UNSIGNED (the "u" in the uint8) integer. It has a range from 0 to 255. Therefore it cant store numbers outside the range (negative numbers are not in the range).

int8 is a SIGNED integer. It goes from −128 up to 127. 
or the int16 (−32,768 to 32,767) is you need to store the values 128 up to 255.

Here is a good table with the ranges of Integers:

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science))